# Need the original length of a list as a "variable" in Haskell, but it keeps changing with recursion

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I have a function in Haskell where I need the original length of a list to act as a static variable would in C, i.e. the length of the list when I first take it in is the value I need.

I'm recursively altering the list (namely via `drop`) as this is necessary for the function to work in the first place, but this of course makes the length of the list update as well and I'm not sure how I can access the original length of the list as it was when I took it in.

There seems to be an issue with the scope of my function and that I need to alter the scope of this value that I desire such that it does not change with the recursion on the list. I'm not sure exactly what the ideal way to go about retaining the original length of the list would be.

Comment: use an inner function and pass the original length of the list to it

Comment: There is a fair chance that you only think you need the length of the list, but you actually don't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a value then keep that variable around.  This is often achieved using a helper function:

```
myfunction xs = helper xs
  where
    len = length xs
    helper [] = 0
    helper ys = len + helper (drop 1 ys)
```